# Develop Create-react-app locally on remote server

Tags: reactjs, express, remote-development

I have a CRA development project created on remote component that i run locally using VSCODE

This project production deployment is served using NGINX to access the build dir.
This server Requires HTTPS.

When I run the project locally and try to make calls to the express backend I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

I have cors setup:

```
app.use(
cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:{port}"],
    credentials: "true",
})
```

);

in react package json:

```
  "proxy": "{ACTUAL_DOMAIN_NAME},
```

and axsios:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Is there a way to run the development instance on the remote server so it will be responsive to code changes? (hot reloading)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Proxy - to redirect all your request to a specific server (one or more) this is good only for development

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

when you use proxy - cors is not a issue

Comment: Thank you for your response. Proxy is set